# UWP ControlTemplate Attached DependencyProperty Binding ImageSource

Tags: xaml, uwp, dependency-properties

I have a templated button, of which I have several attached dependency properties all working just fine with the `{TemplateBinding myExtension:Item.XXX}`.

However, when I come to try and bind to an image URL, I can't do it. If I bind the URL to a textbox in the control template, it shows, but if I use the same binding on an ImageSource, I get nothing.

```
           <Grid.Background>
               <ImageBrush>
                   <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
                       <BitmapImage UriSource="{TemplateBinding extensions:ShopButton.Asset}" />
                   </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
               </ImageBrush>
           </Grid.Background>
```

I've tried using brackets *"(extensions:ShopButtonAsset)"*, I've tried using different property types *string/uri*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using RelativeSource instead:

```
<BitmapImage UriSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=(extensions:ShopButton.Asset)}"/>
```

Comment: UWP has no relativesource

Comment: I am so incredibly wrong! That works like a dream :)

Comment: I've looked for a bunch of different solutions to that problem - this one is the only one that worked. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

```
<ImageBrush>
    <ImageBrush.ImageSource>
        <Binding Path="(extensions:ShopButton.Asset)" **RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"** />
    </ImageBrush.ImageSource>
</ImageBrush>
```